# dataTable inside accordion doesn't update after client filter

Tags: primefaces, accordion, jsf-2.2

I use primefaces in my project and i'm facing some issues with it's components.
I have a dataTabe inside an accordion and both of them are populated with a list in my managed bean. The thing is, before I put this dataTable inside the accordion the filter used to work just fine. When it was into the accordion, actualy the results were corresponding to the filter, but if I click on a comandButton in any row the object that I get from the "f:setPropertyActionListener" is not corresponding to the list after the filter.

Edit:

   -Primefaces 6.0

   -Dynamic Web Module 3.0

   -Java 1.7

   -Mojarra JSF Implementation 2.2.3

---

The .xhtml:

```
<h:form id="frmPrincipal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:toolbar style="background : none; border:0px">
        <f:facet name="left">
            <p:commandButton value="Novo Documento" oncomplete="PF('dlgIncluirDocumento').show();"
                actionListener="#{MyBean.prepararInclusao()}" update=":frmIncDocVal:pngIncDoc
                :frmIncDocVal:pnlTblEmail :frmIncDocVal:pnlEmailNvDoc" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:toolbar>
    <p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" value="#{MyBean.grupos}" var="grupo">
        <p:tab  title="#{grupo.nome}">
            <p:dataTable id="tbValidadeDocFiltrado" widgetVar="#{grupo.idComponente}"
                emptyMessage="Nenhum registro enccontrado" lazy="false"
                value="#{grupo.documentos}" var="item" filteredValue="#{grupo.documentosFiltrados}"
                paginator="true" rows="30" paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="15,30,45">

                <f:facet name="header"><p:outputLabel value="Validade Documento" /></f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="Empresa" sortBy="#{item.tipoDocumento.empresa.nome}" filterBy="#{item.tipoDocumento.empresa.nome}">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('#{grupo.idComponente}').filter()" >
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="#{null}"
                                noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.itensEmpresa}"
                                var="empresa" itemValue="#{empresa.nome}"
                                itemLabel="#{empresa.nome}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{item.tipoDocumento.empresa.nome}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Departamento"
                    sortBy="#{item.tipoDocumento.departamento.nome}"
                    filterBy="#{item.tipoDocumento.departamento.nome}">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('#{grupo.idComponente}').filter()">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="#{null}"
                                noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.itensDepartamento}"
                                var="departamento" itemValue="#{departamento.nome}"
                                itemLabel="#{departamento.nome}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{item.tipoDocumento.departamento.nome}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Documento" sortBy="#{item.tipoDocumento.nome}"
                    filterBy="#{item.tipoDocumento.nome}">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{item.tipoDocumento.nome}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Arquivo">
                    <p:commandLink title="Download" value="#{item.arquivo.nome}" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" rendered="#{item.cadastroDocumentoDownload}" disabled="#{ ! item.icArquivo}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{MyBean.validadeDocumento}" />
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{MyBean.fileDown}" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Opções" exportable="false" width="160">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Alterar"
                        oncomplete="PF('dialog1').show();"
                        disabled="false" rendered="#{item.cadastroDocumentoEditar}"
                        action="#{MyBean.prepararAlterarTipoDocumento()}"
                        update=":idTituloTpDocTituloTelaDlgAlt :frmAltTpDoc:pngAltDoc">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener  value="#{item}" target="#{MyBean.validadeDocumento}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

Print with the command button working:

[image: Print with the command button working]

Print with the command button not working after filter:

[image: Print with the command button not working after filter]

Comment: Parts of the xhtml are most often useless since in more than 75% of the cases the cause is either somewhere else. Please create an [mcve] (see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and post version info

Comment: Ok. Sorry, it's my first question here. I added more info.

Comment: No problem, that is why I comment. In your code there is no dialog while in the screenshots there is and that is where the wrong data seems to be. Please post an [mcve]...